# Bulk delete users from ITIM console?

Tags: identity, identity-management

Hi is there any way ti delete bulk users from ITIM console?

I have a list of client users which are no longer with the organization and I want to bulk delete these users doing it one by one will take a lot of time so I am trying to delete them at once. Is there any way to do in ITIM console?

I haven't tried anything yet but I was thinking to write a python script to do this but I am not sure if it is going to work.